# RevMob Integration for Swift

Tags: swift, revmob

**I have read the RevMob instructions for Swift and I have read an answer to an Swift-RevMob question on here, but it didn't resolve my particular issue. **

I am currently trying to get a fullscreen ad to show.

This is my GameViewController.swift:

```
verride func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


//Start RevMob code
let completionBlock: () -> Void = {
    // do something when it successfully starts the session
     RevMobAds.session().showFullscreen();
}
let errorBlock: (NSError!) -> Void = {error in
    // check the error
    println(error);
}
RevMobAds.startSessionWithAppID("55770fcc17dd7840727aa5e8",
    withSuccessHandler: completionBlock, andFailHandler: errorBlock);

//End of RevMob Code
```

I have defined the modules in my package as "Yes": 
[image]

This is my Bridge-Header:

```
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
#import <RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h>
```

Lastly, this is the error that I am currently getting when I try to build my code: 
[image]

Thanks if you can help!

Comment: Do you have the AdSupport and MediaPlayer frameworks?

Comment: Just checked and yes I have both frameworks in my project.

Comment: You already added the path to your Header.h in your XCode?

Comment: Have you added CoreLocation.framework to your project? Go to Target Settings -> Build Phases, then add it to your project.

Answer (score 1):

`CLBeaconRegion` is part of Core Location from iOS 7 on, so you need to make sure the framework is linked in your project.

Note: in my experience, `CLBeaconRegion` is picked up by Apple as part of app review and they often want to know how you're using beacons – even if the code is just sitting there and you're not planning to use it.

Twice now I have been asked by app review to provide a video of my app detecting a beacon so they can see how it works, so either be prepared to explain your usage or see if there's a library version without it built in.

Comment: I'm using iOS 8. The CLBeaconRegion isn't a framework that's in the linked libraries.

Comment: `CLBeaconRegion` isn't a framework, it's part of the Core Location framework. You should add that and try again.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the required frameworks, you have to add CoreLocation.framework

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. With CoreLocation.framework, also add AVFoundation.framework. Hope that helps